# Proof by contraposition

Tags: logic

Equal weights at equal distances balance.

Equal weights a unequal distances do not balance but incline towards the weight that is at the greater distance.

**How can you proof that:**

A. If we have equilibrium and the weights are equal, then the distances are equal.

**Proof:** Suppose unequal distances and equal weights, then there is no equilibrium. But there is equilibrium, so there must be equal distances.

B. If we have equilibrium and the distances are equal, then the weights are equal.

C. If we have equilibrium and the weights are unequal, then the distances are unequal.

**I tried to proof B and C by contraposition, but this is not possible in my opinion? How can you proof it?**

Comment: I agree with your judgment- this question seems to be lacking information or mistaken. The two statements you are given tell you what happens if the weights are equal, but give you no information about if the weights are unequal, which would be needed to show the last two claims. That is, if we read the first statement as "(equal weights and equal distances) implies balance" and "(equal weights and unequal distances" implies no balance", which is the natural way to read these sentences.

Comment: @KevinLong Indeed, that's also my meaning. So how should you proof it?

Comment: I also do believe there is information lacking. In case this is a homework I would just try to formalise the statements and their contrapositions (symbolic notation) and elaborate on what information is missing.

Comment: I meant that I agree with you that you can't prove it. There's not enough information for you to conclude $b$ and $c$. As mol3574710n0fN074710n said, you can at best try to explain what information you need to prove these things.